# Why can't I replace new line separator?

Tags: python-3.x, replace, utf-8, newline, telegram

I'm working on Python telegram client that sends messages from the app to our API, and I want to exclude some words. In this case should remove some @logins and #tag:

[image: should remove some @logins and #tag]

Here is my code:

```
for w in app.config['EXCLUDED_WORDS']:
    if w in data:
        data = data.replace(w, '')
```

Pretty simple, right? And what I get as a result (lots of new lines):

[image: Lots of new lines]

I've tried very different NL separators such as `#YoCrypto\n #YoCrypto\r #YoCrypto\r\n` but it didn't works. So here is my `print(data.encode('utf-8'))` output:

```
#TAG\n#YoCrypto\xd0\xa0laced \xd0\xb0dditional signal for Bitmex. I will remember to include both exchanges on the same signal for btcusd now on. My apologies for inconvenience.\xef\xbb\xbf@grandcchat\n@grandcsign\n@grandcmargin
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD 01.01.2020**
There are some of excluded words: `['@grandcmargin\n', '@grandcsign\n', '@grandcchat\n', '#YoCrypto\n', 'По всем вопросам (For all questions, please contact): @NickolchenkoGCS']`

We should left a single break at the beginning and at the end of replacing areas, so expecting output should looks like this:

```
#TAG\n\nPlaced additional signal for Bitmex. I will remember to include both exchanges on the same signal for btcusd now on. My apologies for inconvenience.\n\n[Picture from message]
```

Comment: ..and WAIDW stands for?

Comment: @ZF007, what am I doing wrong ofc

Comment: .. that's I guess app-lingo for < 20 years of age ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is using `re` module and replace the word plus any additional new-line characters with empty string. For example:

```
import re

data = b'''#TAG\n#YoCrypto\xd0\xa0laced \xd0\xb0dditional signal for Bitmex. I will remember to include both exchanges on the same signal for btcusd now on. My apologies for inconvenience.\xef\xbb\xbf@grandcchat\n@grandcsign\n@grandcmargin'''

words_to_remove = {'@grandcmargin', '@grandcsign', '@grandcchat', '#YoCrypto', 'По всем вопросам (For all questions, please contact): @NickolchenkoGCS'}

# decode the data (if not decoded already)
data = data.decode('utf-8')

# replace the words plus any aditional new-line character afterwards:
data = re.sub('|'.join(r'(?:[\ufeff]*{}\n*)'.format(re.escape(w)) for w in words_to_remove) , '\n', data)
data = re.sub(r'\n{3,}', r'\n\n', data) # remove excessive new-lines

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
#TAG

Рlaced аdditional signal for Bitmex. I will remember to include both exchanges on the same signal for btcusd now on. My apologies for inconvenience.
```

Comment: It's not that simple: we need to remove some spaces and NLs, but keep all the rest

Comment: @marperia Can you edit your question and put there some inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Is it enought? I've added some